# how to have functions inside a module available to a class?

Tags: python, class, pep8

So I have the following case:

I have a module that has several function definitions. I want to create a class that has those functions available to it.

I just wanted to ask which way is best?
Option1

```
import ModuleWithFunctions

class bla(object):

    ModuleWithFunctions = ModuleWithFunctions
```

Option2

```
class bla(object):

    import ModuleWithFunctions
```

I know option 2 is against PEP 8 so I assume people will say option1, however, what if I wanted everything to be available as:

```
bla.(function)
```

instead of:

```
bla.ModuleWithFunctions.(function)
```

How can I do that with option1?

Comment: It seems to me like a class isn't really what you want in this situation. Mind to elaborate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You generally wouldn't do this.

You *normally* would create a base class in `baseclass_module` instead:

```
# baseclass_module.py

class BaseClass(object):
    def method1(self):
        # ...

    def method2(self):
        # ...
```

Then use that in other modules:

```
from baseclass_module import BaseClass

class Bla(BaseClass):
    # ...
```

Comment: Stahp beating everyone :( :D

Comment: hm... ok so basically use inheritance as a way to achieve this... makes sense... The main reason I didn't want to do this is that the module with the functions I didn't write and wanted as much as possible to not alter the code there

Comment: @evan54: Then I'd expect the functions in that module to *not* work as methods anyway. They wouldn't have a `self` parameter, for one.

Comment: Just in case you're coming from a different language: In python, static methods in classes are *in general* not considered a good idea.

Comment: @MartijnPieters aaa good point they don't! I guess there isn't a 'simple' solution... as in I'll have to write all the methods calling each function

Comment: I still don't see the problem with just using `modulewithfunctions.function`.

Comment: @camelNeck well as @MartijnPieters said you can't access anything inside the class... so it is kind of pointless putting it in there, correct me if i'm wrong. For example `bla.modulewithfunctions.function(arg1)` will need to be written even if `bla.arg1` exists

Comment: Thanks, so he wants to create wrapper methods for the external functions. Makes sense.